# How do I find the worst-case time-complexity of an algorithm with an inner loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose I have a code with two for-loops:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      sum++;
```

How would I find the worst-case time complexity of this code? I've looked at many tutorials on finding time complexity and I understood them. But this one just seems a bit different from those in the tutorials.

Comment: It's different because it does not have a worst case.

Comment: Really? Why's that?

Comment: Can you craft a `N` that is harder than any other `N`? Not all algorithms have a worst case..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets do simple maths.
Value of `i` in each iteration goes as `1,2,4,8... (log N + 1) terms`. In each iteration, the inner loop goes `i` times. Adding up the values of `i`

T(N) = 1 + 2 + ... + (log N + 1) terms i.e. GP with `a = 1` and `r = 2` and `n = (log N + 1)`

T(N) = a[(r<sup>n</sup>-1)/(r-1)]
= 1[(2<sup>(logN+1)</sup> - 1)/(2-1)]
= 2N - 1
= O(N)

So the complexity is O(N) in all scenarios.

Comment: Are you sure the last term in the sequence is logN + 1? Let's say N=100. We now that the value of i can't go higher than N (which is 100 in this case). So that maximum value of i is 64. But if we plug in 100 into logN + 1, we get 3.

Comment: logN + 1 is terms in sequence, not the value of last term. Also, its log to the base 2.

Comment: I see. So if the inner loop was for `(int j = 0; j < N; j++)` instead, the complexity would still be O(N)?

Comment: it's even simpler. why don't u try?

Comment: Here goes: The outer loop iterates (logN + 1) times and the j iterates N times per iteration of i. So I guess I should multiply N*(logN + 1)? So the complexity is O(NlogN)?

Comment: Did i get it right or did I just embarrass myself?

Comment: Yup... you got it :)

Comment: You can accept it if it solves your query.

Answer (score 1):

First consider a simpler case when `N=2^k+1` for some integer `k`. In this case the outer loop has `k` iterations and the overall number of operations is

```
 T(N) = 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k = 2^(k+1) - 1 = 2N - 3.
```

So the worst case complexity is at least `O(2N - 3) = O(N)`.

Now suppose `2^k + 1 < N <= 2^(k+1)` for some `k`. Then

```
 T(N) = 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k = 2^(k+1) - 1 < 2N = O(N)
```

Therefore `T(N) = O(N)`.